# SQLServer Prevent locking issues between two processes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to use a SQL Server table as a message queue. 
One process performs bulk inserts into the table.
A second one queries the table and deletes rows after they are being processed.

My question is: how can I best avoid locking issues between the two processes, if the inserts and select/delete transactions generate row-level locks?

Answer (score 0):

I would look into [sp_getapplock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql) and [sp_releaseapplock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-releaseapplock-transact-sql). Both processes would then try to obtain a lock on the same designated @Resource.

Basic example:

```
DECLARE @LockResult int = NULL
;

BEGIN TRAN MyTransaction

-- Obtain Lock

EXEC @LockResult = sp_getapplock
    @Resource = 'MyResource',
    @LockMode = 'Exclusive',
    @LockTimeout = 10000
;

IF @LockResult IN (0, 1)

    BEGIN

        -- Your process

        EXEC sp_releaseapplock @Resource = 'MyResource'

        COMMIT TRAN MyTransaction

    END

ELSE

    -- Handle failure to obtain lock

;
```